# Form using jQuery minor issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form and it contains four fields. Two of these fields are Country and County. I want that when UK is selected in the country field, the County will be visible and when UK is NOT selected in Country field, the County field will be invisible. Having said that I don't want to make this happen by using the onload event in the `body` due to other jQquery scripts being affected.

NB: I have already a script checking the User IP and auto selecting the country in the Country field. So this part is ready.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a document ready, so this is not technically an onload event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($('#country').val() != 'UK'){
        $('#county').hide();
   };

   $('#country').change(function(){
       if($(this).val() != 'UK'){
          $('#county').hide();
       } else {
          $('#county').show();
       }
   });

});
```

Comment: You will need to adjust your ID's and values, obviously.

Answer (score -1):

By just reading your question and not seeing the code i think you want something like this:

```
if(countryTextBox.val() == "UK"){
    countyTextBox.show();
}
else{
    countyTextBox.hide();
}
```

Comment: I think the issue with using .remove() is that it literally takes it out of the DOM (until page refresh), which is an issue if someone meant to select UK, messes up, and has to correct it. At least, that's my understanding of the .remove() method.

Comment: Using `remove()` permanently removes that element.  What's wrong with a simple `show()` and `hide()`?  You are also missing a critical `)`.